# storyBoard animation rotation issue

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation, rotation, storyboard

i am `rotating` a `button` on `click` at `180 degree`, and its working fine

```
AnimationServices.RotationAnimation((FrameworkElement)sender, 180, 1, "Y"); // working
```

but when i do the same thing by `rotating` it **two times with 90 degree angle** than its not working

```
AnimationServices.RotationAnimation((FrameworkElement)sender, 90, 1, "Y");
AnimationServices.RotationAnimation((FrameworkElement)sender, 90, 1, "Y");  // not working
```

its only `rotating` at one `90 degree` angle

does anyone have any idea about this strange issue ?

**UpDate**

```
internal static void RotationAnimation(FrameworkElement sender, int Angle, int DurationInMSec, String Axis)
        {
            var storyboard = new Storyboard();

            var easingDoubleKeyFrame1 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame
            {
                KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0),
                Value = 0
            };

            var easingDoubleKeyFrame2 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame
            {
                KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(DurationInMSec),
                Value = Angle
            };

            var doubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();

            doubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(easingDoubleKeyFrame1);
            doubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(easingDoubleKeyFrame2);

            var rotateTransform = new PlaneProjection();

            var button = (FrameworkElement)sender;
            button.Projection = rotateTransform;

            Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames, rotateTransform);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames, new PropertyPath("Rotation" + Axis));
            storyboard.Children.Add(doubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames);
            storyboard.Begin();
        }
```

Comment: Can you share exactly what happens in AnimationServices.RotationAnimation method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what's going on if you don't provide the code of your `RotationAnimation` method. Still, it's very likely that this method is trying to execute the same animation two times simultaneously. So you have two animations trying to rotate the same element from 0 to 90 degrees. Which makes... 90 degrees. Either change the rotation angle of the currently executing animation, or wait for the current one to finish executing before launching a new one. Asking two different animations to animate simultaneously the same property cannot possibly provide consistent results.

Edit: After seeing your code, that's indeed the problem. You're creating two animations, that will both rotate from 0 to 90 degrees. You need to chain two animations, and add an "origin" parameter to your method so the second animation will start rotating from 90° (and not from 0). To chain the animation, you can modify your method to return the created animation, then subscribe to the `Completed` event.

Something like that:

```
internal static Storyboard RotationAnimation(FrameworkElement sender, int origin, int Angle, int DurationInMSec, String Axis)
{
    var storyboard = new Storyboard();

    var easingDoubleKeyFrame1 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame
    {
        KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0),
        Value = origin
    };

    var easingDoubleKeyFrame2 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame
    {
        KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(DurationInMSec),
        Value = Angle + origin
    };

    var doubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();

    doubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(easingDoubleKeyFrame1);
    doubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(easingDoubleKeyFrame2);

    var rotateTransform = new PlaneProjection();

    var button = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    button.Projection = rotateTransform;

    Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames, rotateTransform);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames, new PropertyPath("Rotation" + Axis));
    storyboard.Children.Add(doubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames);
    storyboard.Begin();

    return storyboard;
}
```

Then you can call it like that:

```
var storyboard = RotateAnimation((FrameworkElement)sender, 0, 90, 1, "Y");
storyboard.Completed += (s, e) => RotateAnimation((FrameworkElement)sender, 90, 90, 1, "Y");
```

Comment: thanks @KooKiz, its working but when the button rotated by 180 degree
than its content also rotating and so the text (content) displaying its mirror text, how to fix this ?

Comment: for example suppose the content text is `ashok` than after rotating its converting to `ʞoɥsɐ`, how could i fix this ?

Comment: @ashokdamani That's a whole different problem. Please ask it in a separate question, as I may not have the answer and it can serve as reference for future users having the same issue. It's "logical" that the contents of your button rotate along with the button, I'm not sure there's an easy way how to prevent that.

Comment: @ashokdamani Shouldn't you be rotating of 90° in the other way to prevent that? (use 90 as origin, and -90 as rotation angle)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31510/discussion-between-ashok-damani-and-kookiz)